# Why is my React functional component returning several times? I need it to run only once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, axios, fetch

I am making a request from client to server to validate the user when they're logged in. From the request, I will update 5 piece pieces of state on the 'UserContext' context provider (using useContext hook).

My code below reaches the endpoint ok, and the data is returned fine. I need the function to run a total of 1 time and update each context state individually once the response has been returned. But, the function runs a total of 6 times, each logging different results as the function processes each line to be updated.

The first time, it logs each of the states' individual initial values. It then runs again with the fName updated, then a third time with fName + lName updated, then a fourth time with fName + lName + email updated and so on... until it's run through 6 times with the final one being the correct output that I need.

```js
const CheckUser = async () => {

 const {
    validUser, setValidUser,
    fName, setFName,
    lName, setLName,
    email, setEmail,
    companyName, setCompanyName
    } = useContext(UserContext);

 try {
    let userData = await axios
      .post(
        `${serverURL}/checkuser`,
        { someData: 1 },

        {
          withCredentials: true,
          credentials: 'include',
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        setFName(response.data.fName);
        setLName(response.data.lName);
        setEmail(response.data.email);
        setCompanyName(response.data.companyName);
        setValidUser(response.data.validUser);

        //   return response.data;
      });
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error('Erroring out');
  }

  console.log(fName, lName, email, companyName, validUser);
};
  
export default CheckUser;
```

Why is it doing this, instead of just once as per my console.log at the bottom of the code? And how do I make it so it only runs once. I think I'm doing something obviously wrong here but I can't seem to find any answers on here.

Another component relies on validUser being true in order to avoid being redirected to a sign-in page, but when I use this function, because it's initial validUser is false/undefined, before eventually becoming true, it sends them to the sign-in page - despite being logged in OK.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated and acknowledged. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `useEffect` Hook inside functional components.

- It is same like the componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and componentWillUnmount combined.
- It is used when data is fetched from an api and the api is rendered only once

  ```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.post(`${serverURL}/checkuser`,
    { someData: 1 },

    {
      withCredentials: true,
      credentials: 'include',
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (response.data.success) {
            setFName(response.data.fName);
            setLName(response.data.lName);
            setEmail(response.data.email);
            setCompanyName(response.data.companyName);
            setValidUser(response.data.validUser);
        } else {
            alert('Failed to get data')
        }
    })
  ```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense and I can see why that should work. However, for some reason, it is now unable to read - the alert is being invoked. I don't know if that is related to the API request itself.

Comment: Furthermore, I have realised the data is a success as I can log the data right in the response. However this data refuses to save into the context's state.

Answer (score 0):

Because every `API`call in your function updates the state causing a `re-render` which calls your API again and again.

Put your API call in the `useEffect`

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    // your api call here.
}, [])
```

Doing this will make sure the API call is run just once.